# Problem with add value to registry with cpp

Tags: c++, regedit

I am trying to add value to the registry in order to run my program on system startup and after execution in Regedit. `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

is only the first letter of the path "C"

```
int start_with_os() {
    long result;
    HKEY hkey;

    result = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, _T("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run"),
        0, KEY_READ | KEY_WRITE | KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hkey);
    if (result != ERROR_SUCCESS) return 1;

    char* fpath = new char;
    GetModuleFileNameA(NULL, fpath, MAX_PATH);

    const size_t cSize = strlen(fpath) + 1;
    wchar_t* wc = new wchar_t[cSize];

    size_t outSize;
    mbstowcs_s(&outSize, wc, cSize, fpath, cSize-1);

    OutputDebugStringW(wc);

    result = RegSetValueEx(hkey,  _T("sysservice"), 0, REG_SZ, (BYTE*)wc, strlen((const char*)wc));
    if (result != ERROR_SUCCESS) return 1;

    RegCloseKey(hkey);
    return 0;
}
```

The output from variable wc is the correct path.
`C:\Users\Piotrek\source\repos\myprogram\Release\myprogram.exe`

Comment: `strlen((const char*)wc)` as `wc` is wide-char string, this will return 1 always as each character will be null-terminated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code you provided, I guess your project is using the Unicode character set.

[Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regsetvalueexw) says that the last parameter of `RegSetValueEx` is in bytes.

> cbData
>
> The size of the information pointed to by the lpData parameter, in
> bytes. If the data is of type REG_SZ, REG_EXPAND_SZ, or REG_MULTI_SZ,
> cbData must include the size of the terminating null character or
> characters.

So, change

```
result = RegSetValueEx(hkey,  _T("sysservice"), 0, REG_SZ, (BYTE*)wc, strlen((const char*)wc));
```

to

```
result = RegSetValueEx(hkey,  _T("sysservice"), 0, REG_SZ, (BYTE*)wc, (_tcslen(wc) + 1) * sizeof(TCHAR));
```

should work.

---

Edit: Thanks @john for the comment, `char* fpath = new char;` is also an error.

Consider to use `TCHAR fpath[MAX_PATH];` directly.
And the following code also needs to be changed to T string functions.

Comment: @user13469033 It might not since  `char* fpath = new char;` is an error, it should be  `char* fpath = new char[MAX_PATH + 1];`

Comment: @john i'll consider it. Thanks for advice